# Julia: append to an empty vector

Tags: vector, julia

I would like to create an empty vector and append to it an array in Julia. How do I do that?

```
x = Vector{Float64}
append!(x, rand(10))
```

results in

```
`append!` has no method matching append!(::Type{Array{Float64,1}}, ::Array{Float64,1})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your variable `x` does not contain an array but a type.

```
x = Vector{Float64}
typeof(x)  # DataType
```

You can create an array as `Array(Float64, n)` 
(but beware, it is uninitialized: it contains arbitrary values) or `zeros(Float64, n)`, 
where `n` is the desired size.

Since `Float64` is the default, we can leave it out.
Your example becomes:

```
x = zeros(0)
append!( x, rand(10) )
```

Comment: How do you extend this to a 2D array? For example I have a number of type Array{Float64,2} that I want to append to a blank array of the same type but I'm gettting the error 'ERROR: MethodError: `append!` has no method matching append!(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Float64,2})'.

Answer (score 49):

I am somewhat new to Julia and came across this question after getting a similar error. To answer the original question for Julia version 1.2.0, all that is missing are `()`:

```
x = Vector{Float64}()
append!(x, rand(10))
```

This solution (unlike `x=zeros(0)`) works for other data types, too. For example, to create an empty vector to store dictionaries use:

```
d = Vector{Dict}()
push!(d, Dict("a"=>1, "b"=>2))
```

#### A note regarding use of `push!` and `append!`:

According to the Julia help, `push!` is used to add individual items to a collection, while `append!` adds an collection of items to a collection. So, the following pieces of code create the same array:

Push individual items:

```
a = Vector{Float64}()
push!(a, 1.0)
push!(a, 2.0)
```

Append items contained in an array:

```
a = Vector{Float64}()
append!(a, [1.0, 2.0])
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It was indeed the difference between append! and push! that was tripping me up :)

Answer (score 15):

You can initialize an empty Vector of any type by typing the type in front of []. Like:

```
Float64[] # Returns what you want
Array{Float64, 2}[] # Vector of Array{Float64,2}
Any[] # Can contain anything
```

Answer (score 8):

New answer, for Julia 1. append! is deprecated, you now need to use push!(array, element) to add elements to an array

```
my_stuff = zeros()
push!(my_stuff, "new element")
```

Comment: Running your code example results in error: ```julia> my_stuff = zeros(); push!(my_stuff, "new element")
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching push!(::Array{Float64,0}, ::String)
Closest candidates are:
  push!(::Any, ::Any, ::Any) at abstractarray.jl:2064
  push!(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any...) at abstractarray.jl:2065
  push!(::Array{Any,1}, ::Any) at array.jl:862
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0```

Comment: @Evgeny are you on Julia 1.0? I'm not sure this will work the same on other versions, especially earlier versions

Comment: did you try running the code yourself? `zeros()` create an array of type Float and you are trying to add strings to Float. My version is 1.1.1. and you can see the error in code also [here online](https://repl.it/@epogrebnyak/VelvetyQuestionableEnvironments).